# Help Rendering ASP.NET MVC View from a Console App

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC View. On my MVC WebApp, it works great.

I would like to be able to (from a console app) render the View out as an HTML Email. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is going to be, the part I'm struggling with is Rendering the View.

Is there any way to do this from a console application?

The webapp simply calls a web-service and formats the data nicely so the console application will have access to the same web-service; however, the ActionResult on the controller is protected by [Authorize] attributes, so not just anyone can get at it.

Comment: Is the challenge rendering or authorizing?

Comment: Either -- if I have to use WebRequest then authorizing would be my issue, because I can't just send credentials can I? If there is a more clevor way, like adding a reference to my mvc-app, then rendering would be the issue. Long story short, I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using HttpWebRequest and the info provided here: http://odetocode.com/articles/162.aspx

From the article:

```
    // first, request the login form to get the viewstate value
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;         
    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(
         webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
      );
    string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();         
    responseReader.Close();

    // extract the viewstate value and build out POST data
    string viewState = ExtractViewState(responseData);       
    string postData = 
         String.Format(
            "__VIEWSTATE={0}&UsernameTextBox={1}&PasswordTextBox={2}&LoginButton=Login",
            viewState, USERNAME, PASSWORD
         );

    // have a cookie container ready to receive the forms auth cookie
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

    // now post to the login form
    webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;        

    // write the form values into the request message
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(postData);
    requestWriter.Close();

    // we don't need the contents of the response, just the cookie it issues
    webRequest.GetResponse().Close();

    // now we can send out cookie along with a request for the protected page
    webRequest = WebRequest.Create(SECRET_PAGE_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

    // and read the response
    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    responseReader.Close();

    Response.Write(responseData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I assume you are using forms authentication. Just authenticate, grab the session header cookie and copy it to your new web request.

Comment: I've never done this before, any resources on doing that? Do I simply add a `NetworkCredentials` on to my WebRequest class?

Comment: Only if you are using Windows authentication.

Comment: I am using Forms Authentication. With a plain [Authorize] attribute on the ActionResult...

Comment: Let me get home I will get back to you